# Relative path above document root in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, error-handling, path, relative-path, document-root

Is there any equivalent to php's

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../directory/above/root/';
```

in htaccess? I want to place custom error scripts above webroot and tried something like this without success...

```
ErrorDocument 400 ../error/400.php
ErrorDocument 400 /{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/../error/400.php
```

Comment: I don’t think that is possible. Apart from a hard-coded message, the manual says you can either specify a local URL path, or a full absolute URL for a redirect. “local URL path” can not go above the document root _by definition_, in my understanding. File system paths and URLs are two different things.

Comment: Thx CBroe, I guess you are right :)

Answer (score 0):

// Root path for file manager
// use absolute path of directory i.e: '/var/www/folder' or $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/folder'
$root_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

// Root url for links in file manager.Relative to $http_host. Variants: '', 'path/to/subfolder'
// Will not working if $root_path will be outside of server document root
$root_url =